# Is there a way to add custom validations on user-input data while using Flask-appbuilder inbuilt forms?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-restful, flask-appbuilder

I am building a web-app using flask appbuilde and stuck at the following issue for a week now.

On the documentation, the instructions seem pretty straight forward:

```
class MyView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(MyModel)
    validators_columns = {
        'my_field1':[EqualTo('my_field2', message=gettext('fields must match'))]
    }
```

However, when I implement this exactly, on UI it says "invalid input" even when inputs are correct thus hindering form submission.

My Code(views.py):

```
class DelModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Dell)
    base_filters = [['cap_id', EqualTo, get_user]] #current user
    list_columns = ["cap_id", "s_code", "s_name", "sos", "date_of_change"] 
    #base_order = ("cap_id", "asc")
    validators_columns = {
        'cap_id':[FilterEqualFunction(get_user, message=_('fields must match'))]
    }


def get_user():
    return g.user.username
```

I want to add a validation that checks if while adding new entry cap_id == username.

Am I missing any link here? I have tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by doing the following:

I removed cap_id from add_coloumns. I am pre-populating it by using the default value, which is current_user and now it works perfectly fine. Yay!!